# Ticks, exclamation marks and question marks on my Windows 7 Explorer folders?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer

A lot of my folders on my C drive have strange icons on their thumbnails - either a tick, question mark or exclamation mark, and I am not sure what they are.

I found online this may be something related to McAfee, potentially the backup status of files. However, although my PC has McAfee, it is a simple virus scanner and I do not have any backup software. The red exclamation mark actually appears on my C drive itself.

Any help on what these are and how I can remove them? I did attempt to delete the Icon Cache, and restart the PC but this hasn't fixed it.

[image: Windows 7 Explorer folder errors]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These overlay icons are from a version control system. I think yours are from Subversion SVN.

If your are really sure, you want to remove these icons, you can delete the hidden `.svn`-folder in the top folder where the icons appear.

Another possibilty is to deinstall the subversion-application e.g. "TortoiseSVN" or something like that.